# VS Code will not debug or run any code. Throws error: "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am having an issue with my VS code where I can't run or debug code anymore. It throws a VS code error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" I have tried clearing all my user and program setting as well as reinstalling VS code.

This is happening with any code I run. I have tried Python and JavaScript.

Launch.json file

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true
    }
]
```

}

[image: Screen Shot of issue]

[image]

Comment: Related?: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58225 Please show your launch.json configuration. Do any problem indicators indicate that you are using deprecated fields? If so, which ones?

Comment: nope nothing seems like I am using deprecated fields.

Comment: Do you get any more information in the various output logs? (`View > Output`) And how are you launching your file? (via the run and debug window and its keybindings or via the play button at the top right?)

Comment: Nothing is in the output log or debug console. It seems like VS doesn't even attempt to run anything. One new thing I discovered is if I try to run my script in the Terminal it runs just fine, but opens an new window and doesn't run in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. There must have been an issue with an extension I had installed. I disabled all extensions and enabled only the python one and it fixed the issue.